# MongoDB - Use field in the document as regex expression

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am storing regex expressions in MongoDB and would like to use them for queries.

Documents structure:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "regex_expression": "^[^@ ]+@(bar\\.com)$"
}
```

I tried the following query but it doesn't work.

```
db.collection.find({$expr: {$regex: ["foo@bar.com", "$regex_expression]}})
```

Is it possible to do this kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`$regexMatch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/#mongodb-expression-exp.-regexMatch) operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $regexMatch: {
      input: "foo@bar.com",
      regex: "$regex_expression"
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v84W5aRmNZb)